# VBA - Paste text from inputbox into cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want a user to type a text or a number into a inputbox that pops up when you click a button. I tried different methods i found on the Internet and tried to modify the codes that they work for me.

First I tried this but after i clicked OK the box disappeared and nothing happened:

```
Sub inputbox()

    Dim mlt As String
    Dim myString As String
    myString = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bericht_BOSCH").Cells(2, 6).Value
    mlt = Application.inputbox("Insert your age:")

End Sub
```

Then i tried to tell my code where the text from the Inputbox has to go and added 2 rows to my code:

```
Range("B6").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Now my code selects the cell B6 after I click OK but it doesn't paste the code there. Now my question: What did I do wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub inputbox()
    Dim mlt As String
    Dim myString As String

    myString = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bericht_BOSCH").Cells(2, 6).Value
    mlt = Application.inputbox("Insert your age:")

    ActiveSheet.range("B6").value = mlt
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much I feel a little dumb now xD. Have a nice day!!

Answer (score 1):

You can even do it in one line:

```
Sub TestMe()
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bericht_BOSCH").Cells(2, 6) = Application.inputbox("Insert age:")
End Sub
```